# Why does writing to file change the content (hash)?

Tags: vim, hash, echo, nano

I noticed, that when trying to generate some hashes after copy-pasting them into a file with vim, the hash is not as it is supposed to be. Same when file was opened and written out. Same behavior with nano, so there must be something I am mising.

```
$ echo -n  "foo" | openssl dgst -sha256
2c26...e7ae
$ echo -n "foo" > hash.txt
$ openssl dgst -sha256 hash.txt
SHA256(hash.txt)= 2c26...e7ae
```

But when I open hash.txt with nano or vim and quit without inserting anything, I subsequently get the following hash: `b5bb...944c`

I also noticed that without opening the file and writing out I do not see the output when using `cat` or `head`. Was the encoding changed?

Comment: Somehow you inserted a newline into the file. In any event, I cannot reproduce your results.

Comment: `echo foo | openssl dgst -sha256` => b5bb…4944c. This is the same `foo` with a newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most text editors, including Vim, save the file with a newline at the end when you quit.  That's because according to POSIX, a text file is either empty or ends with a newline, so most users expect and want that behavior.

As you've noticed, adding a newline at the end changes the hash, and the hash you're getting is consistent with the sequence `foo\n`, where `\n` is a newline.

If you have a recent enough Vim, you can control the behavior mentioned above by setting `nofixeol`, which will preserve the existing line ending, or lack thereof, on the last line.

Comment: I believe without `nofixeol`, `noeol` is documented to work only with `binary`.